# Should we make a canonical for how to set up data packs?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

Minecraft's data pack system allows for the creation of complex command systems that can accomplish more than normal command blocks can. It also allows for the setup of loot tables, predicates, and other helpful things that can further enhance what your creations can do. Data packs are also becoming the primary way of creating these commands machines rather than command blocks.

There are a lot of commands questions that will come in that can be best accomplished with a data pack, usually through predicates or loot tables. While data packs are more flexible, it is harder to set up because it requires a lot of file manipulation. A guide to setting up Minecraft data packs would greatly benefit the community, being to point to an official resource on Arqade.

Would this be beneficial yet, or is it too early for that?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the inner stuff on Arqade, but do we have a spot that exists for something similar already? Like, more of a Wiki than a Q&A site?

Comment: Do you mean something like the creation of the dummy datapack linked in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/369363/171580) (in "how better" section)? Because everything else depends completely on what you actually want to do with the datapack. There's also [this wiki article](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Datapack) already, which contains the entire folder structure and links to all important other articles about parts of datapacks.

Comment: @FabianRöling In my imagination, such a question would simply show how to set up the folder structure, how to set up `pack.mcmeta`, and point out where you can go from there. I understand that the wiki shows this all in more detail but I feel that a step-by-step tutorial would be better.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf We have Community Wiki questions, if you think such a canonical would be best suited as one.